# how to measure an angle?

Tags: ros, integration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear,

I want to measure yaw angle (radian). What command should I use ?
In my c++ file, I used like this;

```
  double q0 = odom->pose.pose.orientation.w;
  double q1 = odom->pose.pose.orientation.x;
  double q2 = odom->pose.pose.orientation.y;
  double q3 = odom->pose.pose.orientation.z;
  double omega = odom->twist.twist.angular.z;
  double psi = atan2(2*(q0*q3+q1*q2),1-2*(q2*q2+q3*q3));
```

This yaw angle produce only between -pi and pi.
But I want to measure directly the yaw angle in radian without the limitation of -pi and +pi, that is, measure the counter-clockwise one and half circling as +3 pi and the clockwise two circling as -4*pi.

One alternative can be coded this way:

```
  double omega = odom->twist.twist.angular.z;
  double delta_psi = omega*dt;
  psi += delta_psi;
```

But the heading angle psi might accumulate some integration error. Do I have to implement more accurate integration method ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12668/how-to-measure-an-angle?/) by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2012-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To derive Euler Angles from Quaternions, you need to know (or define) the sequence of rotations around the coordinate axes. You can only get the Yaw in this context. Take a look at this **very** nice document.  [Representing Attitude: Euler Angles, Unit Quaternions, and Rotation Vectors (2006)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.110.5134)

Otherwise I'd recommend to make use of a linear algebra library (e.g Eigen). Conversion can be done in one line:

```
Eigen::Quaterniond orientation(w,x,y,z);
orientation.toRotationMatrix().eulerAngles(0,1,2)
```

EDIT: I looked at the conversion formulas for all the angle sequences and could not find anything similar to your calculation. Should rather look similar to this (seq: 0,1,2):

```
atan2(2xy + 2wz, w*w + x*x - y*y - z*z)
```

compare to Formula (290) in linked document.

EDIT: Actually your formula is correct, because the norm of the quaternion is always 1:

```
w*w + x*x - y*y - z*z = 1-2*(y*y+z*z)
```

Output should be between -PI and PI.

---

Originally posted by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) with karma: 191 on 2012-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on 2012-01-23**:
I edited the original question. Could you check it ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the getYaw() function in tf: http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a33e93f413622e296d0a2a93b252bbb4b

In general, tf has a couple of handy functions for working with quaternions that represent angles in the plane.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on 2012-01-23**:
I edited the original question. Could you check it?